# How to get reference to UIView in scene dock?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have `UIViewController` with 2 `UIViews` (scenes) in dock:
[image]

How can i display it in whatever place I need in my `UIViewController`? In other words, how can I get reference to this views from within my controller?

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3, Xcode 8

### 1. Create a Reference

You can drag the UIViews to your ViewController and create outlets for them.
[image]

### 2. To Show UIView

You want to add it to the view as a subview. I hooked up those two buttons you see in my scene:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var view2: UIView!

    // SHOW THE VIEWS
    @IBAction func showView1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view1.center = view.center
    }

    @IBAction func showView2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view.addSubview(view2)
        view2.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: 100)
    }
}
```

### 3. To Hide the UIViews

You will have to remove them from your view. I created actions for the Close buttons on the UIViews:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var view2: UIView!

    // SHOW THE VIEWS
    @IBAction func showView1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view1.center = view.center
    }

    @IBAction func showView2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view.addSubview(view2)
        view2.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: 100)
    }

    // HIDE THE VIEWS
    @IBAction func hideView1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view1.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func hideView2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view2.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Mark, Can you tell me how to animate adding a view from bottom. Like for any view inside the view heirarchy, we can make an outlet of constraint and animate that constraint. 

Can we do this for the views in scene dock also ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz, yes, you first add the view to below your current view controller's bounds:

view1.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.height + view1.frame.height)

Then animate it up into position using a new center value like:

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
    self.view1.center = self.view.center
}

Answer (score 1):

Within my `UIViewController`'s code keep references using `@IBOutlet`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dockView: UIView!
```